# Angular 2.0 Final + Translation + Webpack?

Tags: angular, internationalization, webpack, translation

I just wanted to know how to provide translation support for my Angular 2.0.0(final) application which uses Webpack(1.13.2) for module bundling (not SystemJS).

I can get examples of Angular 2.0 i18n online, but all of those are done with SystemJS and not with Webpack.

Does anyone know how to do Angular2 i18n with Webpack ?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to follow the instructions below:

1. Add `import 'ng2-translate'`
2. Copy those i18n files to the assets folder. An example can be with the following plugin:
    
      `new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: helpers.root('src', 'public', 'i18n'), 
          to: 'assets/i18n'
        }
      ])`

Taken from thread: https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/issues/121

**Update:** In Angular 2 RC6 They have release a i18n support as you see here: http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/09/angular-2-rc6_1.html
You could use the `TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, LOCALE_ID` barrel imports to utilize that. See an example here: https://github.com/StephenFluin/i18n-sample

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: How to use the native i18n support in Angular 2.0, instead of using a library ?

Comment: Thank you Gabriel. That should help me to get started.

Comment: Glad to hear @VigneshKumar. If it's OK with you can you mark the question as answered?